# Smooks is failing to return comma separated values when double quote is encountered in the records

Tags: java, csv, double-quotes, smooks

I have a CSV file, I am spcifying "comma" in smooksConfig file as separator. But smooks is failing to retrive values whenever one of the values has double quote(eg.21" TV, 10" Screen)
if no double quote in my record, smooks works good.

thanks.

Comment: Please let me know, if you need more info or clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for this, in CSV I changed double quote with a special symbol & in application I replaced special symbol with duble quote.